# Java Lucene Classpath problems ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, lucene, classpath

I'm having problems trying to run a Java file that uses Apache Lucene.

I can compile it since I have the .jar file in my classpath but when I want to run the .class file, I have to add this parameter `-classpath .:lucene-core.x.x.jar`, if I don't I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloLucene
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloLucene
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Could not find the main class: HelloLucene.  Program will exit.
```

Do I have to add the classpath to the jvm also? If so how do I do this?

Here's the output I get when I echo my CLASSPATH:

```
ricardo@ricardo-laptop:~/Desktop/lucene/Indexer$ echo $CLASSPATH
/home/ricardo/lucene-3.4.0/lucene-core-3.4.0.jar:/home/ricardo/lucene-3.4.0/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar
```

Comment: are you using any IDE for this or doing on console ?

Comment: It works if I use Netbeans but I doesn't when I use the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that's not found is your class, i.e. `HelloLucene`. Not the library.

Your class is probably compiled under `bin` or `target/classes`, so your classpath has to point whereever it is, i.e.

```
-classpath target/classes:...
```

Comment: I do have the .class file in the same folder

Comment: `java -classpath .:lucene-core-3.4.0.jar Indexer` Indexer being the java class

Comment: `Indexer.class` and lucene jar are in the same directory where you run the command from? Also what's the full package name of the `Indexer`?

Comment: Sorry I messed up with the Indexer.class, its HelloLucene.class from this tutorial `http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html` and yes, they're on the same directory, that's the only way I can run the file

Comment: No problem. When you say "that's the only way I can run the file" do you mean it works when you run it from the directory where the HelloLucene.class is?

Comment: if I execute `java HelloLucene` I get the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloLucene` error, but if I run it like `java -classpath .:lucene-core-3.4.0.jar` I have no problems

Comment: I see. Yes, that's because HelloLucene is not on the `CLASSPATH` (which only has lucene jars). If you want to execute `HelloLucene` from the command line you need to a) specify its location with `-classpath` (or `-cp`) as you did before, or b) add its location to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. One way or another, JVM needs to know where to find your class. Netbeans does it automatically that's why you didn't have a problem running it from Netbeans.